# Is it possible to have a custom XML Signature element?

Tags: xml, xsd, digital-signature

Hi I am new to xml signatures, currently I am reproducing a signed xml request based from a sample that was given to me.

It looks like:

```
<ns:CompanySignature>
  <ns:SignedInfo>...</ns:SignedInfo>
  ...
</ns:CompanySignature>
```

Is it possible to have a custom Signature element like CompanySignature? Because the samples that I saw from internet were are all using the standard Signature element set by W3C

```
<ds:Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
  <ds:SignedInfo>...</ds:SignedInfo>
  ...
</ds:Signature>
```

Comment: Please refer the link to ask valid question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

XMLDSig standard defines Signature tag for signatures. Custom tag just won't be recognized by other signature validators.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I contemplated and thinking that my question should be "Is it possible for the Signature to reside on another namespace"

Comment: @EzerWidKruz do you mean replacing ds: with something else? Yes, this is technically possible yet *some* validators might not understand this as well. But in general yes, the prefix is replaceable and some organizations do this. Technical possibility to replace the prefix depends on the language and tool. Our XML signing library support such replacing.

Comment: Yeah, prefixes can be arbitrary but in my case they are using custom tag name of signature instead of <ds:Signature> (which is standard) they are using <rps:CompanySignature> with "rps" stands for another namespace

Comment: You can change the namespace but not the node name, that's what I initially wrote in the answer. Custom node name won't be recognized as a signature node.

Comment: @EzerWidKruz Note that if the parser is under your control, then you can use any node names, it's a compatibility question.